# Space requirements when running rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two partitions, `/disk1` and `/disk2`, each with 100GB of space, and both of them are `45%` full now.

I want to rsync `/disk1` to `/disk2/backup/`, is it safe to use rsync for this purpose?

```
rsync -avc /disk1 /disk2/backup/
```

e.g. How much temp space are required for the above command? How to estimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always run rsync in `dry-run` mode, that will tell you the total size of the files transferred and more.

```
rsync --dry-run -avc /disk1 /disk2/backup/
```

Comment: Hi, my concern would be the temp file size created during the transfer, not the total size of transfer itself..

Comment: Rsync works in-place. There are (nearly) no temporary files.

Comment: my understanding is rsync will only update the file in an atomic fashion when the transfer is completed, so there must be temp file in the receiver side, right?